# How to make projectiles come out straight?

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I am making a programme to launch projectiles (Not my own programme, its from a youtube video) from an enemy npc and they only come out forwards in certain directions. here is my programme:
agent.SetDestination(transform.position);

```
    transform.LookAt(player);
    if (!alreadyAttacked)
    {
        alreadyAttacked = true;
        Invoke(nameof(ResetAttack), timeBetweenAttacks);
        
        //Attack settings
        Rigidbody rb = Instantiate(projectile, transform.position, Quaternion.identity).GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        rb.AddRelativeForce(transform.forward * 32f, ForceMode.Impulse);
```

Am I doing something wrong? Also the enemy from which the prohjectile launches is a 1x1x1 capsule if that changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

AddRelativeForce is in local space so if you pass Vector3.forward it will be the forward direction of the object the rigidBody it is attached to. On the contrary transform.forward is in World Space. You can read more [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/31169/explanation-local-vs-global-space.html). If you want to use AddRelativeForce try this,

```
rb.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.forward * 32f, ForceMode.Impulse);
```